# Do I have to land at the end of my turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, flight, dnd-adventurers-league, falling

I was told by my AL DM that when you fly at the end of your turn you must return to the ground or at the end of the round take falling damage.

I can't find this rule set anywhere.  All I can find is:

> Races that have Flying at level 1 are illegal for AL play. ([ALPG](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/events/adventurers-league-resources), p.3)

And from [Sage Advice (twitter)](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/08/06/hover-flying-creature/):

> Can a flying creature without the hover trait stay in one place while airborne, or does it need to move each round?
>
> A flyer that lacks the hover trait can stay aloft with-out moving each round.

Which seems to contradict his answer.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Tangentially related: [What happens when you run out of movement while jumping?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/57165)

Answer (score 47):

**You do not have to land to avoid falling under most circumstances**

There is no mention of this in the [SRD](http://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#Flying_Movement) entry about flying movement, which only states the following about flight and falling:

> If a flying creature is knocked prone, has its speed reduced to 0, or is otherwise deprived of the ability to move, the creature falls, unless it has the ability to hover or it is being held aloft by magic, such as by the fly spell.

Note that this requires *the ability to move*, not movement. Even without hover or magic you may fly in place if you are unhindered by the conditions mentioned.

**It is possible that your DM has mistakenly applied language from the Barbarian's *Totemic Attunement (Eagle)* to all flight**:

> While raging, you have a flying speed equal to
>   your current walking speed. This benefit works only in
>   short bursts; you fall if you end your turn in the air and
>   nothing else is holding you aloft